# in Angular 2 how index.html identifies angular tag and how it identifies root modules, please explain how the flow works

Tags: angular, indexing

I am new to angular 2 . I am just doing sample programs, could someone explain how the flow works from index.html and where we are entering those configuration details like from index.html it has to look for main.ts and so on.

Comment: I suggest starting with a hello-world app and experimenting

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/architecture

Answer (score 2):

There are few scripts added during building of a project by CLI .

- Inline.js
- Style.bundle.js
- Main.bundle.js

It is not directly seen in index file

- Main.bundle.js file starts angular 2 application .
- Main.ts file in our project structure starts or bootstraps the angular 2 project
- Main.ts file has code which shows which component to bootsrap for example it has code like platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule); this will go to app.module.ts file  which contains the name of the component to be started first.
- Now it goes to app.component.ts and there it sees component decorator which has selector tag and it contains an element name which is found in index.html file .Inside this tag the html mentioned in component decorator will be loaded.

Comment: So every project should have main.ts or the name is configured somewhere, also how are we defining bundles and what is the purpose of those bundles.